# Are Oracle Equi-joins ANSI Compliant

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I had a quick Google but couldn't find a question and an answer which answers this directly.

Are equi-joins like this ANSI compliant:

```
t1.a = t2.a
t2.b = t3.b
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/4598/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you show is not joins, it's conditions.

This is an equi join as of SQL-86:

```
select *
from a, b
where a.x = b.x;
```

This is an equi join as of SQL-92:

```
select *
from a
inner join b on a.x = b.x;
```

So both are ANSI compliant joins. The first one has always been; the second one only for little more than 20 years.

Comment: Ah interesting, this will save me lots of time, since I was unclear to as where I saw statements like I posted, did they need turning into joins. Thanks Thorsten.